# ¿Cómo hacer que los registros en un campo de una entidad no se repitan?

Tags: symfony2, fos-user-bundle

```
<?php

namespace SEICBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Programa
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="programas")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SEICBundle\Entity\ProgramaRepository")
 */
class Programa
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Facultad")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="facultad_id",referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $facultad;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre_programa", type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $nombrePrograma;

    /*To String*/
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->nombrePrograma;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombrePrograma
     *
     * @param string $nombrePrograma
     * @return Programa
     */
    public function setNombrePrograma($nombrePrograma)
    {
        $this->nombrePrograma = $nombrePrograma;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombrePrograma
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNombrePrograma()
    {
        return $this->nombrePrograma;
    }

    /**
     * Set facultad
     *
     * @param \SEICBundle\Entity\Facultad $facultad
     * @return Programa
     */
    public function setFacultad(\SEICBundle\Entity\Facultad $facultad = null)
    {
        $this->facultad = $facultad;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facultad
     *
     * @return \SEICBundle\Entity\Facultad 
     */
    public function getFacultad()
    {
        return $this->facultad;
    }
}
```

Cómo hago para que en el campo "Nombre Programa" de la imagen anexada, no se repitan los registros, que los nombres de los programas sean únicos. Cómo debo validar eso en el `FOSUSERBUNDLE`, o de que forma tengo que hacer la validación para que sean nombres únicos, muchas gracias.[image: IMAGEN ADMIN BD]

Comment: Tengo esta entidad llamada "Programa" con un campo llamado nombrePrograma    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre_programa", type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $nombrePrograma;    ¿Como hago para hacer que ese campo al ingresar un registro verifique si ya existe ese nombre y no deje ingresar un nombre igual, no deje ingresar nombre duplicados, ejplos/ Arquitectura y despues vuelva a ingresar Arquitectura, donde debo hacer esa validación?... pdta.. soy un poco novato en FOSUSERBUNDLE

Comment: Bueno lo tienes bastante sencillo según lo que parece que buscas. Simplemente añade unique=true en @ORM\Column de nombre_programa y listo.

Comment: Amigo eres un genio!!, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentaba si te refieres a que simplemente no pueda haber dos programas con el mismo nombre simplemente deberías configurar dicha columna como única.

Sería:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre_programa", type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $nombrePrograma;
```

mandas un update al esquema y listo.

Comment: Amigo eres un genio!!, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Nada, si te sirvió no olvides de marcarla como válida, saludos!